# c# get paths to specific method

Tags: c#, codeql

How can I get all different paths to specific method?

```
import csharp
import DataFlow::PathGraph

class TaintTrackingConfiguration extends TaintTracking::Configuration {
  TaintTrackingConfiguration() { this = "TaintTrackingConfiguration" }

  override predicate isSource(DataFlow::Node source) {
    exists(MethodAccess ma | ma = source.asExpr().(MethodAccess))
  }
  override predicate isSink(DataFlow::Node sink) {
    exists(MethodAccess ma | ma.getTarget().getName() = "MyMethodName")
  }
}

from DataFlow::PathNode source, DataFlow::PathNode sink, TaintTrackingConfiguration c
where c.hasFlow(source.getNode(), sink.getNode())
select source.getNode(), source, sink, "A -> $@ -> B", sink.getNode(), "CCC"
```

tried to get a tree like paths to specific method

Comment: this is definitly no valid C#, no idea about codeql, though. You need to be way more specific on what you want to achieve and what you've tried, as well as how thiis attempts failed your expactations.

Comment: I googled CodeQL and [yep, that looks like that](https://codeql.github.com/). It's not C# though. I'm guessing you tagged C# because you're trying to analyze C# code, right?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel yes